# Selected option in localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the selected option to be stored in localstorage, I track it in another select component and convert the received data and add it to localstorage , but I can’t figure out how to implement select and option. I get the data from GraphQl , so let's assume that the option contains the values "one", "two", "three" Thanks

```
const Currency_Query = gql`
{
    currencies{
      label
      symbol
    }
  }
  `
  ;

  

class Currency extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currencies: [],
    }
  }
    
    componentDidMount = async () =>{
      const response = await client.query({
        query: Currency_Query
      })
      this.setState({
        currencies:response.data.currencies
      })
      
    }
    
    render() {
      return(
        
          <div className={s.select}>
             <select>
            {this.state.currencies.map((currencies) =>(
              
                <option>
                    <div className={s.option} >{currencies.symbol} {currencies.label}
                    </div>                  
                </option>
                )
              ) 
            }
                </select> 
                
                
                
        </div>
            
        );
    }
}

export default Currency;
```

Answer (score 0):

select has value (UPDATED ON SELECTING AN OPTION) option which can have a default. You listen to change of the select value once it changes you store the value to local storage. **YOU CANT HAVE ELEMENTS INSIDE OPTION**

````js
const Currency_Query = gql`
{
    currencies{
      label
      symbol
    }
  }
  `
  ;

  

class Currency extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currencies: [],
    }
  }
    
    componentDidMount = async () =>{
here_set_default_local_Storage_value
      const response = await client.query({
        query: Currency_Query
      })
      this.setState({
        currencies:response.data.currencies
      })
      
    }
    
    render() {
      return(
        
          <div className={s.select}>
             <select
value={choice}
        defaultValue={"here_put_the_localstorage_value"}
        onChange={(e) => setlocalstorage_value_to_e.target.value)}

>

            {this.state.currencies.map((currencies) =>(
              
                <option>
                    <div className={s.option} >{currencies.symbol} {currencies.label}
                    </div>                  
                </option>
                )
              ) 
            }
                </select> 
                
                
                
        </div>
            
        );
    }
}

export default Currency; ```
````

Comment: When you select a specific value (I have a currency on my site), the currency on the entire site changes and everything works fine and localstorage saves the value for the entire site which currency is selected. But in select after updating the site, the currency is included by default and you need to select it again.

Comment: set a default localstorage (maybe onmount) value. it can be null at first then set that local storage value to be the select `default value`. so the select is null selected at first.  the on updating the select it will update the local storage value which is also the select default. that way even if you reload the site the default of the select will remain last selected unless you delete

Comment: I didn't quite understand you. can you demonstrate based on my code

Comment: i have added hope it makes sense now....edited on the answer

Comment: I don't quite understand from your code how your code adds to localstorage. I pass the values via onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChange(e)} to the parent component. I don't quite understand how select values will be stored in localstorage in your code